# Under (the) circumstances

Tags: definite-articles

I wonder, if I need to place definite article here: *Under (the) circumstances, we change every second*, if I mean no specific circumstances, but want to express some general idea? I mean, it's a silly question, but somehow it sounds strange without article.

Comment: If you "mean no specific circumstances," why not just write or say "We change every second"?

Comment: Semantically, *under **the** circumstances* seems an unlikely usage here. I suspect what OP actually intends to say is something more like *"We [can] change from minute to minute, **according to circumstance**"* (where idiomatically we usually refer to *minutes, rather than *seconds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two common ways of using *under...circumstances*.

- Under **the** circumstances
  Refers to a particular situation which is already known and relevant to the written sentence; this is the standard use of the definite article
- Under **certain** circumstances
  Refers to a situation which has not been specifically described, but which does have the enumerated consequences

> **certain**
>   **2.** *[attributive]* Specific but not explicitly named or stated:
>   *he raised certain personal problems with me*
>   *the exercise was causing him a certain amount of pain*
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/certain?q=certain)

There's also *Under **no** circumstances,* which simply means that there is no situation which would cause the action, and is equivalent to **never**.

Answer (score 0):

The article should be used here.

> *Under the circumstances, we change every second.*